# Ordering Mandelbrot edge points at some level of detail

Tags: fractals, mandelbrot

Is there known way of assigning natural numbers (ordering) of Mandelbrot fractal edge points? Obviously there is an infinite number of such points, but at certain level of detail we can count them and order them. I'd like to order them in such way so they form a continuous path without any intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Edge points can be ordered with external angles, as the landing point of external rays. External angles are measured in [turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)), usually [binary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Mathematics/binary)

Here is [the image by Claude](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wakes_near_the_period_1_continent_in_the_Mandelbrot_set.png) [image]